# Can't take screenshots on a rooted device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, system-error, screenshots

I can't take screenshots on my **rooted** Android 4.0.3 tablet. It's a Genesis GT-1230 running some modified ROM, and apparently the power + volume down combination is disabled.

The screen is 10.1", 1024 x 600 pixels.

- I have GoLauncher installed on it, and its screenshot feature produces a result like this:

(resolution 600 x 988, not resized or edited in any way)

[image]

- However, if I deny root permissions for GoLauncher, the screenshot result goes like this:

(resolution 249 x 410, not resized or edited in any way)

[image]

- I installed [this screenshot app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.screenshot), it requires root, I give root permission, and it displays an error message, something along the lines of "*error on fb0*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to take screenshots after rebooting the device and running the same screenshot app with root permissions.

The GoLauncher screenshot feature gives the same results, corrupt image when ran as root and very small image when ran as non-root.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing it that way? Not surprised that the app that was downloaded failed to work!

Android 4.0.4 has native screenshot facility in place - hold down Power button and press the volume down key simultaneously.

A screenshot will be captured and stored on `/sdcard/Screenshots`

Comment: Sorry, it's an Android 4.0.3 tablet, fixed that. Tried the power + up combination, didn't work.

Comment: @ruda.almeida see my edit - its power button + vol down key!

Comment: doesn't work for me...

Comment: @ruda.almeida obviously the ICS ROM was modified to remove the "standard" shortcut in screen capture.... :(  (It became standard since ICS came out) What is the name of the device as matter of interest?

Comment: It's a Genesis GT-1230.

Comment: I suggest you re-edit your question to include that information to make it easier. Should have stated that from the start!